# Need help figuring out how this code access data from the reddit API with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Alright so I have this code here

```
  componentDidMount() {
    var _this = this;
    var cbname = `fn${Date.now()}`;
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = `https://www.reddit.com/reddits.json?jsonp=${cbname}`;

    window[cbname] = function(jsonData) {
      _this.setState({
        navigationItems: jsonData.data.children
      });
      delete window[cbname];
      document.head.removeChild(script);
    };

    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
```

I can't figure out at all how this accesses the reddit.json call to retrieve data, it looks very confusing for someone who just learned how ReactJS works.
Also this is the state + component constructor, incase its needed:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeNavigationUrl: "",
      navigationItems: [],
      storyItems: [],
      title: "Please select a sub"
    };
  }
```

For the rest of the code refer to https://github.com/ssorallen/react-reddit-client , the code piece is located at src/app.js

Looking at the above code, I understand everything up to the line that instantiates script.src
After that, I dont understand what's going on, even the window[cbname] part. I tried googling around pieces of it but it got too confusing, especially whats really being done with window[cbname], and why the code piece is appending a child(script) to the head of the document after deleting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is using the JSONP API - which essentially requires the API to wrap the JSON into a function callback

eg `{ "foo": "bar" }` with `callback=foo` would call a global function called `foo` and pass the JSON as an object.

in this case, it registers `window['fn' + Date.now()]` as the callback. once the API calls it, it sets state and deletes the global function.

see [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

TLDR: JSONP needs a global function on the window object. when called, it sets state and removes itself and the script tag. JSONP is useful to circumvent CORS

Comment: Thank you! This explained it perfectly